# Correct version of Node/ECMA for linting

Tags: vscode-extensions, prettier, prettier-vscode

I'm using **Prettier** in **VSCode**, but it appears to be flagging mistakes that I think are ok.

Specifically, if I test a variable like:

```
if (myObject?.property1?.property2) {
  ....
}
```

(Not sure of the correct name for using questions marks like this) then it flags the question marks as invalid.

I can see there is an `ecmaVersion` setting in `.prettierrc` but this doesn't seem to do anything, and anyway, as I understand it, Node versions don't exactly follow ECMA versions anyway.

What can I do to make Prettier correctly lint my code?

Comment: What's the exact message Prettier prints? Maybe some of the question marks are not needed, which is a good reason for a linter warning.

Comment: It puts a wavy red line under the first question mark, but no explanation. If you delete that question mark, it moves on to the next, and so on.

Comment: You can hover with the mouse over the word with the wavy line and it will show a tooltip with more information. Also you probably have an entry in the PROBLEMS tab for each marked problem.

Comment: A restart brought up the explaination - but it just says `unexpected token '?'`. But it IS expected! Which is my point. It's valid syntax, I think...